# Redshift Disk Full error when inserting data

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I was doing

```
insert into table (select * from view)
```

That View involves a lot of inner joins of large fact tables and window functions.
I was reading the article "Top 10 performance tuning techniques for Amazon Redshift" This Tip #6: Improving the efficiency of temporary tables cloud be relevant https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-techniques-for-amazon-redshift/ Redshift cloud be storing the intermediate step in memory when inserting and caused a disk spill. This is the execution plan in csv.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TmxbYf6WzWqHmtXSYl0GRX3j2QgFriyP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you post the explain plan for this insert?   I suspect that there is a log of data growth due to the joins.

Comment: here is the execution plan: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TmxbYf6WzWqHmtXSYl0GRX3j2QgFriyP/view?usp=sharingc

Comment: You don’t have an insert problem.  You have a select problem.  You have a bunch of rows being created during execution with “DISTINCT” to bring the size down.  Cost metrics is up to 1.1 quadrillion - that’s big.  This view needs some work.  I’d repost with SQL and test data, if possible, and get help with query improvements